# How to create clientId and clientSecret for OAuthTokenCredential paypal rest api

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using paypal rest api and i don't know how to create client_id and clientSecret. Please let me know if you have any idea...

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to follow the following steps:

- Go to Paypal developer Site here https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications (you must have Paypal account, of course)
- Click on Create App on right side of page
- Choose name of your app and click Create App
- Now you can see and manage everything include client ID and secret.

Comment: This is just for sandbox mode or this will work for live mode too... if not, how I can create one live access to paypal? Thanks.

Comment: @LucasRodriguesSena There is Tab for "Sandbox or Live" mode on top right hand side. You can switch over to "Live" or non-sandbox details by clicking on "Live Tab menu"

Answer (score 8):

Go to PayPal developer dashboard https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/myapps

Click **Create App** button to create an app

[image: STEP 1]

Then, you will see **Client ID** and **Secret**

[image: STEP 2]

Comment: how to get the credentials for live account?

Answer (score 0):

Link: [Click Here](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications)

I found "My Apps" in the footer part.

[image]