# Paypal TransactionSearch API Operation (NVP) python

Tags: python, paypal

I want to write a `Python` script with runs once a week and bring all orders from that week.

I understand that this can be done with: Paypal TransactionSearch API Operation (NVP)

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/

However there is no information how do I get the initial connect to this API.

I understand that it might required a `client_id` and `client_secret` ? 
I found this topic [How to create clientId and clientSecret for OAuthTokenCredential paypal rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20494944/how-to-create-clientid-and-clientsecret-for-oauthtokencredential-paypal-rest-api) but it's about the Rest API which is something else.

I'm a bit confused here about how to start.
It seems like most of the information is about how to actual do the transaction search but no information about how to do the connection.

Comment: The rest API is generally the global API that handles everything you will ever do. The endpoint, which in this case is api.paypal.com is the starting point. In order to access specific functions, such as transaction search you must specify a method to the rest API. This is generally what follows the base URL and tells the API what you're trying to do. Then you usually pass parameters to filter results, all in the same URL.  This link should have all the info you need. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/rest/api/

Comment: @Chris in my case I don't have a store. people are forwarding money as transactions in paypal itself. I want once a week to get all these transactions from paypal into my database. The link you provided does not explain how to do the initial connection to paypal. There are explanations about get and post requests but that is after you established a connection to paypal.